# Can believers of Jehovah work for the navy?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses

So my husband asked me how I would feel about him joining the navy, granted he wouldn’t actually be going on a ship to fight he would be working in construction for the navy but not harming anyone, I am a little conflicted about it because we want our own house and not have to worry so much about finances. He recently lost his job and the way this economy is; it’s hard for him to get work right now. Neither of us are baptized but at the same time we are wanting to get closer to Jehovah and hopefully get baptized but I jus thought since he wouldn’t be going to war and just be doing construction that it would be okay?

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/60940/23657  Related

Comment: If you are studying with JWs, then this would be something to speak with them about. If you are not studying but attending meetings, then I suggest speaking with the elders about this. They are there to help you see Jehovah's view on the matter.

Comment: _Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor._

Answer (score 4):

Baptised Jehovah’s Witnesses who join the military are at risk of being disfellowshipped, which results in being shunned by all Witnesses, including family members.  Disfellowship Offences, found in the 2011 edition of the Elder’s Manual ‘Shepherd the Flock of God’ include:

> No 2 – Apostasy which includes rebellion against Jehovah’s organization – Watchtower 63 7/1

> No 19 – Non-neutral activities (involvement in politics and the military) – Pay Attention to Yourselves and to All the Flock (ks91-E) p.96

> No 20 – Military service and non-military service including working casual work  – Pay Attention to Yourselves and to All the Flock (ks91-E) p.96

***However, certain civilian work within military organisations has been made a matter of conscience (1996 Watchtower 5/1 p.20).***

Although the official line is that they "do not interfere with those who choose to serve in the armed forces”, that does not apply to baptised Witnesses. Taking up arms, going to war and taking life would be considered a serious sin which is a disfellowship offence for baptised Witnesses.

Comment: Perhaps specific to the OP q. An unbaptized associate who joined the military would have no action taken against them. They would put themselves in a position where no advancement could be made beyond their current status. If they were serving as an unbaptized publisher that would be revoked.

Comment: Not coming from the U.S. I don't know if working in the Navy on construction is the same as signing up as an employee of the Navy and undergoing military training.  The 1996 Watchtower says that "certain civilian work within military organisations has been made a matter of conscience."  Is that no longer the case?

Comment: Op states husband is thinking of “joining the navy”. That is different from working as civilian on a job that navy has contracted with an outside source. Oaths are sworn when one joins any branch of military.